# asp.net page's preinit event

Tags: asp.net, events, preinit

I am new to asp.net. I have an aspx page and i have to write some code in its PreInit event.
From where i find PreInit event on the page. 
As we double click on button to get button click event(or selecting button and select event from property pane)
Plz reply me ASAP.

Answer (score 3):

Man, why do you need the mouse?

If you need to write some code into PreInit just write the code:

```
protected virtual void OnPreInit(EventArgs e)
{
   base.OnPreInit(e);
   //your code
}
```

or in class constructor add a event handler for it:

```
...
PreInit += new EventHandler(SomeMethodName)
...
```

and define the event handler method

```
private void SomeMethodName(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //your code
}
```

And by the way, check a .Net Framework book and a Visual Studio manual.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do some reading:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx#lifecycle_events

Comment: I checked that page out before I began searching, it isn't very helpful on actually interacting with the event.