# Event handler does not get called

Tags: c#, asp.net, event-handling

In the following code, the asp does not enter the action listener (Button1_Click).
Can anyone help?

```
protected void Project_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Courses.ActiveViewIndex = 0;

        String ConnStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyRuMoR"].ToString();
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnStr);
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("ViewProjects", conn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@course_code", "PHYS305");

        SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        int c = 1;

        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            String name = rdr.GetString(rdr.GetOrdinal("name"));
            int p_id = rdr.GetInt32(rdr.GetOrdinal("p_id"));

            LinkButton lb = new LinkButton();
            lb.ID = p_id.ToString();

            lb.Text = "Project " + c + " is: " + name;
            form1.Controls.Add(lb);

            lb.Click += new EventHandler(this.Button1_Click);

            c++;
        }
        conn.Close();
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Write("Hello");
    }
```

Comment: You mean event handler. Action listener is a Java concept.

Comment: You better change your logic and use Repeater instead, binding its data source in the `Project_Click` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes not just understanding dynamic controls you need to TRULEY understnad them
This is one of the best article on them by a ASP.NET team memeber.

[TRULY UNDERSTANDING DYNAMIC CONTROLS](http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/archive/2006/08/25/TRULY-Understanding-Dynamic-Controls-_2800_Part-1_2900_.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

You need to read up on the [ASP.NET page lifecycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx).

When it comes to dynamic controls, you need to *recreate them* on postback, or they will not exist and the attached event handler will not fire.

Dynamic contorls are best created on the [`PreInit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.preinit.aspx) event of the page.

As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6042807/1583):

```
protected virtual void OnPreInit(EventArgs e)
{
   base.OnPreInit(e);
   //your code
}
```

Comment: not in the init but PreInit. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx

Comment: thank you for your reply but could you please illustrate more? I don't really get what is the PreInit stage of the page.

Comment: I'm new to asp.net and this my first project, so i'm a little bit lost and don't understand how to add a dynamic control on the PreInit event of the page.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put all or the part of your code that creates dynamic controls inside the Pre_Init event of page life cycle, something like this

```
protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   LinkButton lb = new LinkButton();
   lb.ID = p_id.ToString();

   lb.Text = "Project " + c + " is: " + name;
   form1.Controls.Add(lb);

   lb.Click += new EventHandler(this.Button1_Click);
}
```

Then only it will achieve what you want.